# Dependence graph with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

im trying to do some like this with tikz:

[image]

I try to do it like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={draw,thick,
    align=justify, % Blocksatz in Noden
    anchor=north% Anker der child node für level distance
}]

\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=60mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=60mm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=30mm]

\node {$T_1$}
child {node {$T_9$}; &
\node {$T_2$}; &
child {node {$T_3$}
    child{ node {$T_5$}}
    child{ node {$T_6$}
    }
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it seems, i messed something up..
Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Note that it is generally more useful to include a complete example than a mere fragment of code i.e. a complete, small compilable document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. This means people can easily copy-paste-compile to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi, cfr. Thank you. I will do that in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with help of the package [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw}}]
T_1 \arrow{d} & T_2 & T_3 & T_4 \arrow{dl} \arrow{d} \arrow{dr} \arrow{drr} & &\\
T_9 & & T_5 & T_6 & T_7 & T_8
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may adapt everything to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    ,cells={nodes={draw,minimum width=.7cm,minimum height=.7cm}}
    ,column sep=1em%,row sep=...
    ,every arrow/.append style={-latex}
    ]
T_1 \arrow{d} & T_2 & T_3 & T_4 \arrow[start anchor = south west, end anchor = north east]{dl} \arrow{d} \arrow[start anchor = south east, end anchor = north west]{dr} \arrow{drr} & &\\
T_9 & & T_5 & T_6 & T_7 & T_8
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A `forest` solution which uses a `phantom` root note to align the first row of nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    draw,
    thick,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [-latex, thick, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- (.child anchor) \forestoption{edge label};
    }
  }
    [, phantom
      [$T_1$
        [$T_9$
        ]
      ]
      [$T_2$
      ]
      [$T_3$
      ]
      [$T_4$, calign primary child=2, calign=child
        [$T_5$
        ]
        [$T_6$
        ]
        [$T_7$
        ]
        [$T_8$
        ]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image: forest tree]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\psset{
  framesize = 24pt,
  nodesep = 0pt,
  arrows = ->
}
\begin{pspicture}(9.75,2.75)
  \multido{\rA = 0.5+1.75, \rB = 4+1.75, \iA = 1+1, \iB = 5+1}{4}{
    \fnode(\rA,2.25){T\iA}
    \rput(\rA,2.25){$T_{\iA}$}
    \fnode(\rB,0.5){T\iB}
    \rput(\rB,0.5){$T_{\iB}$}
%    \ncline{T4}{T\iB} % not working for some reason
  }
  \fnode(0.5,0.5){T9}
  \rput(0.5,0.5){$T_{9}$}
  \ncline{T1}{T9}
  \ncline{T4}{T5}
  \ncline{T4}{T6}
  \ncline{T4}{T7}
  \ncline{T4}{T8}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

**Note**

I have no idea why the outcommented line isn't working and why I have to use the last four lines inside the `pspicture` environment instead.

Answer (score 1):

A tikz tree solution. The lines from parentnode to level 1 is suppressed via a style

```
edge from parent/.style={draw=none}},
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[level distance=1cm,every node/.style={draw, thick, 
    align=justify, % Blocksatz in Noden
    anchor=north% Anker der child node für level distance
},->,>=stealth',]

%\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=10mm]
%\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=20mm]
\tikzset{level 1/.style={sibling distance=2cm, edge from parent/.style={draw=none}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.35cm,edge from parent/.style={draw}}
}

\node[draw=none]{}
child {node {$T_1$}
         child {node {$T_9$}}}
child{node[] {$T_2$}}
child{node[] {$T_3$}}
child{node[] {$T_4$}
         child{ node[] {$T_5$}}
         child{ node {$T_6$}}
         child{ node {$T_7$}}
         child{ node {$T_8$}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with a `TiKZ matrix`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every nde/.style={draw,thick,align=justify}]
\matrix (T) [matrix of math nodes, nodes={draw}, column sep=5mm, row sep=5mm] {
T_1 & T_2 & T_3 & T_4 \\
T_9 & & T_5 & T_6 & T_7 & T_8\\
};
\draw[->] (T-1-1)--(T-2-1);
\foreach \i in {3,4,5,6}
    \draw[->] (T-1-4)--(T-2-\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]